# Faking preloader screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout, preloader

I make a preloader page using valid tutorials for my webpage, 
similar to https://codepen.io/bommell/pen/OPaMmj.  the problem is I want to make this preloader work somehow fake, without using any heavy contents pics nor videos (iframe .....) In other words, I want to make this preloader a default screen before my actual project, so in js file, I use setTimeout and clearTimeout but it doesn't work, what should I do?
**the preloader works properly whenever I use Iframe or other tricks**

```
function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ document.body.addClass("loaded"); }, 3);
  }

  function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
  }
```

can anyone help me faking the preloading screen?

Comment: how are you calling `myFunction` and `myStopFunction` .... document.body (or any element for that matter) does not have an `addClass` method

Comment: So how should I invoke it?

Comment: yes, you should call those functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` tells the browser to perform an action after the specified amount of time. (The unit is miliseconds - 3ms might be a bit short).

`clearTimeout` tells the browser to cancel the action you set up with `setTimeout`.

What you seem to be trying to do is adding the `"loaded"` class to `body`, so there is no need to use `clearTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.body.classList.add("loaded"); }, 3000);
```

will add the `"loaded"` class after three seconds.

Comment: if only html elements actually HAD an `addClass` method

Comment: @NoNameProvided - yes, I know, because I use it - but thanks for the lesson

Comment: @ Jaromanda X and @ NoNameProvided Thank you  for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

First, create a loader. It might just be an image with an infinite rotate on it by css, it might be complete overlay 1 z-index higher than that of your current content. Whatever it is, doesn't really matter, just that it can obscure your 'loading' content. Give this div an id, ie loader.

Second, when everything loads, hide the loader, delete it if you want to.

```
window.onload = function () {
   document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none"; //HIDE THE ELEMENT
   document.getElementById("loader").style.remove(); // COMPLETELY REMOVE IT
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot but if you mean just adding your code to this line of code: function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ document.body.addClass("loaded"); }, 3);
  }   ------I tried it and did not solve the problem

Comment: It's not supposed to. It's not going to be used in tandem with setTimeout. You're supposed to use this standalone and take out the setTimeout. Take for example, in live web applications that have to load. If you use setTimeout, then it will remove the loader after the delay set. However, if you use window.onload, then it will remove the loader when and only when the entire page itself has loaded. This makes it much better practice even for fake preloaders, as it will still be useful if the page gets more complex.